# Make custom shipping method available in admin order

Tags: admin, cart, shipping, shipping-methods

I have built a shipping module that calculates a number of things, then makes three options available for the customer to choose from. I am not using any of the built-in options for shipping.

When I try to create an order (from scratch or a reorder) from the admin, it gives me the message `Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.`

How do I make my shipping method available to the admin? Do I have to create a separate module for the admin or is there xml I can add to make this available?

I am running version 1.9.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ECB_Shipping>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </ECB_Shipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ecb_shipping>
                <class>ECB_Shipping_Model</class>
            </ecb_shipping>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <ecb_shipping>
                <class>ECB_Shipping_Helper</class>
            </ecb_shipping>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <ecb_shipping>
                <active>1</active>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <model>ecb_shipping/carrier</model>
                <title>ECB Shipping Methods</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            </ecb_shipping>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <ecb_shipping translate="label">
                    <label>ECB Shipping Methods</label>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Shipping Method title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                    </fields>
                </ecb_shipping>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

For the cart functions, I won't paste them all here, but some of the items in question have to do with getting the customer's cart. Do these things work for the admin?

```
$count = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty();
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
```

This is how the functions are being initialized:

```
class ECB_Shipping_Model_Carrier
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
        implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface {
```

The easiest method, the better. If this isn't possible and there is a way to just override this completely and have the admin enter the shipping, that's a fine end solution.

Comment: Does your custom shipping method follow the right way of creating custom shipping methods ? Understand does your model extend Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract and implement Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface ? Maybe a look here could here: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

Comment: It is. I've updated the question, but I'm thinking I can probably get away with using a module I found that uses shipping conditions that behave like the coupons.

Comment: Try having a look at Owebia Shipping 2 module, really powerful, lets you create a lot of rules.

Answer (score 1):

No need create separate module for the admin or is there xml.

Your bellow code is not working both end (frontend & admin)

```
$count = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty();
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
```

So please use bellow code in model file `ECB_Shipping_Model_Carrier` and it is no issue both end (admin & frontend) and shipping method also available to admin

```
<?php

class ECB_Shipping_Model_Carrier
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface

{

   ...
   ...
   ...
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = 0;
        $count = count($request->getAllItems());

        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }

        ...
        ...
        ...

        return $result;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
?>
```